# How to place a '/' in an incoming request in Spring

Tags: java, spring, url, encoding

An external, unmodifiable service uses '___' instead of '/' for ~parameters~ path variables in URLs. So '`http://localhost:9091/infra/Test/Test`' becomes '`http://localhost:9091/infra/Test___Test`'.

For every incoming request, I need to make sure that any possible '___' gets converted into '/' without changing the mapping before the request is processed. This is what I came up with:

```
@Component
public class SlashFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public String getServletPath() {
                final String originalUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getRequestURL().toString();
                return originalUrl.replace("___", "/").replace("%20", " "); // emphasis
            }
        };

        filterChain.doFilter(wrapped, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getPathInfo().contains("___");
    }
}
```

However, this seems to effectively do nothing. If I receive `http://localhost:9091/infra/Test___Test`, it becomes `http://localhost:9091/infra/Test/Test` and I get an error:

```
DELETE /infra/Test___Test http: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Invalid contextPath: 'http://localhost:9091/infra/Test/Test': must start with '/' and not end with '/'","path":"/infra/Test___Test"}
```

So, I thought let's encode the `/` here! I changed the marked line to:

```
return originalUrl.replace("___", "%2F").replace("%20", " ");
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
DELETE /infra/Test___Test http: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR {"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Invalid contextPath: 'http://localhost:9091/infra/Test%252FTest': must start with '/' and not end with '/'","path":"/infra/Test___Test"}
```

It looks like it converts the % as well, and '`%2F`' becomes '`%252F`'. I'm kinda getting lost here, have spent all day fiddling with this and the RequestWrapper, but so far nothing works. Anyone got an idea how to make it work?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need do, you want change the incoming request into a new one in fly? Or what the expected situation, its a redirection what you want or?

Comment: @AL I have the incoming parameter 'Test___Test' which I want to turn into 'Test/Test' without Java interpreting it as another endpoint, and I need to check this for every incoming request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I realized that there was no real use for using path variables and we changed to request parameters. That was a lot easier than hardcoding some filter